# Delphi: image of Action doesn't appear on Tool Button

Tags: image, delphi, button, toolbar, taction

All is on a frame. I have an action list, there is an action with an image, the image appears in the action. I have assigned the action to a tool button but the image doesn't appear on it.

[image]

Why?
Delphi XE.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to assign the imagelist to the toolbar's `Images` property.

Comment: Ok, I thought I was wrong to assign an image list to the action list and to the tool bar. Thanks!

Comment: @maxfax Yeah, I too sometimes wonder why can't the "action consumer" read the image info directly from the action, without the need to assign imagelist twice.

Comment: Because ImageIndex is just an integer offset. And you might link the toolbar's Images property to your SmallImages (16x16) or LargeImages (32x32) depending on your needs.